# Custom case field that is Editable for users produces error message when they try to edit it

Tags: case, custom-field, permissions, web2case

I've created a Custom Case Field called Value. It's a picklist with two different options users can choose.

If I try to create a Case with this field as an administrator, it works. If I login as a customer and try to fill out this field in the New Case form we have setup, it produces the following error message:

"We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help."

If, on the other hand, I try to make a new case as a customer, but do *not* pick a value for that picklist (if I just leave it at --None--), the case gets created just fine. So it seems like a permissions issue, but I just don't get it. The field is completely editable in the Layout / Field Security settings.

Comment: Can you give more details on the "new case form"? What is it? If it's a Visualforce page sharing the mark up will help us.

Comment: It's actually the Global Action "NewCase" that I'm using. Well, I made a copy of it and I'm using it for customers in the Community.

Comment: Do you have record types on case? Is the customer assigned a different record type and maybe the picklist values aren't assigned to that record type?

Comment: @DanielHoechst No record types.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Lightning-Experience-Global-Action-results-in-We-couldn-t-find-the-record-you-re-trying-to-access-It-may-have-been-deleted-message&language=en_US&type=1 This is the solution, in case anyone was wondering.